# Force an installer to execute when it wants to be called by a different installer

Tags: installation, windows-server-2019

I'm trying to install some software (Rockwell Studio 5000 v27) on an unsupported OS (Windows Server 2019). If I launch setup.exe, it will let me install certain components, but not the main/most important component (Logix Designer), because it's not supported on this OS.

I understand that it's not supported, but I've installed 15 other unsupported versions on this OS so far, both newer and older, and with a bit of cajoling I've gotten them all to work. It's just this one intermediate version that the developers decided to do a compatibility check and prevent the installer from even launching.

I thought maybe I could bypass this by running the installer msi for Logix Designer directly, as the main setup.exe just calls the Logix Designer msi file during the process, but when I try to run it, I just get a popup "You must run setup.exe to install Logix Designer".

Is there any way to force it to run independently? I understand that it still may or may not work, but based on the fact that v26 and v28 (and 13 other versions) worked just fine once they at least made an attempt, I want to at least give it a try.

I'm fine with messing with (and potentially breaking) the installer file to make it work if that's what's required, I have access to download a clean copy at any time if I need to.

Comment: The starter program is probably passing along arguments to the secondary installer. You'll need to find those arguments in order to run this installer.

Comment: That makes sense - can you expand on how I might go about this?

Comment: Where does the starter app fail? If it runs at least a little you may be able to observe it using Process Explorer to see the arguments it's supposed to pass. There are other tools for peeking into simple executables. But really, you should probably look into support for the product and see what documentation they offer on it and whether it includes how to run the msi manually.

Comment: Thanks. The support for this product doesn't extend anywhere near what I'm currently trying to do, and since it's not supported on this OS they're not willing to dedicate any time to helping me find back doors into it. I've done a little more testing and will post an update below

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this one out... in the 27.00.001-Studio5000-Web folder there is a subfolder called Config. In it is an XML File called Logtix_V27, edit it with Notepad ++. Find the line "Product Name="Logix Designer" Version="27.00" ... etc". Go to the second to the last line where it says OperatingSystem and for WIN10 change `Unsupported="no"`. Then if you run though the installer you should be able to install logix 27.

Comment: http://www.plctalk.net/qanda/showpost.php?p=822734&postcount=8

Answer (score -1):

Update which answers the question as I posed it, but still doesn't solve my overall problem:

I ran the installer with logging turned on to see where it stopped. It stopped on an action called "Error_MustRFS" (must run full setup?). I then opened the msi file with Orca.exe, found Error_MustRFS in the CustomAction table, and deleted it. Now the installer starts, but gets stuck on "Computing Space Requirements", before throwing another error:

Error 1606. Could not access network location Studio 5000

Most likely @music2myear is correct in their comment on my initial post - the setup.exe executable probably passes some parameters to this msi file. If I knew what these parameters were I could possibly call the msi by command line and pass it the required parameters, but I'm not sure how to find that information. Since it's a case of the installer refusing to even try, I can't run it and look at log files to see where it falls over - it just won't run at all